# How to get inverse prediction from a bspline smooth fit in R

Tags: r, smoothing

I was using functional data analysis techniques to smooth a discrete dataset. I was using the fda package and the function smooth.basis. It gives me a fitted smooth object, yet now I need to get the inverse of it. The codes are something like the following:

```
basisobj<-create.bspline.basis(c(0,1),7)
fit=smooth.basis(argvals=Data$Time,y=Data$Score,fdParobj=basisobj)$fd
```

I wish to know what is the value of Data$Time when Data$Score is, say 20.

I did try the inverse.predict function but it could only give the result for lm function.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem with this is that your function is not guaranteed to be monotonically increasing or decreasing and that for the inverse problem there may then be multiple possible solutions. I would recommend using the scam package instead and then using monotonically increasing or decreasing splines, and use approx() to do inverse prediction, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957486/calibration-inverse-prediction-from-loess-object-in-r